# An array of pointers to a linked list elements

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I've got a linked list (Tproduct) and I want to create an array of pointers to this, e.g.:

```
e1 -> e2 -> e3 -> e4 -> e5 -> e6
|           |                 |
v           v                 v
p[0]       p[1]              p[2]
```

My declaration looks like this:

```
Tproduct *arrayOfPointers = (Tproduct*)malloc(N*sizeof(Tproduct*));
```

Is this proper? I'm not sure if it's Tproduct *arrayOfPointers or Tproduct arrayOfPointers.

Regards.

Comment: Tproduct *arrayOfPointers says arrayOfPointers is pointer to Tproduct.Tproduct **arrayOfPointers says arrayOfPointers is pointer to Tproduct *.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want an *array of pointers*, you should do:

```
Tproduct **arrayOfPointers = (Tproduct**)malloc(N*sizeof(Tproduct*));
```

This code does exactly what you want - allocate memory for `N` `Tproduct` pointers.

---

#### What's wrong with your code?

- Your type of `arrayOfPointers` is a pointer to `Tproduct` - so, you can manipulate it *like<sup>1</sup> an array of objects*, but **not like an array of pointers to the objects**.

  <sup>1</sup> It's still a pointer, not an array. That's why *like*.
- In case you want an array of objects, you should allocate memory for `N` objects, not `N` pointers:

  ```
  malloc(N * sizeof(Tproduct))
  //                ^^^^^^^^ - Note: not a pointer
  ```

---

> And now I want to write a function returning an array of this type. What's the prototype?

```
Tproduct** fill();
```

Should do the work. Example of function:

```
Tproduct** fill()
{
    Tproduct **arrayOfPointers = (Tproduct**)malloc(N*sizeof(Tproduct*));
    // do some stuff
    return arrayOfPointers;
}
```

But I suggest rename your function to, say, `allocate_array` or something like this. `fill` doesn't mean *allocate*.

Comment: and now I want to write a function returning an array of this type.. what's the prototype?
Tproduct** fill();
Tproduct**[] fill();
Tproduct[]** fill();
are not working :/

Comment: `TYPE* ptr = malloc(N * sizeof *ptr)` is preferable ... shorter, more general, less coupling, no masking of undeclared `malloc` (which will default to `int` if the header is missing) ...